# Can't get Images from the iPhone device folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, device, nsurl

I'm trying to get some images from the device (iPhone) and show them on screen.

The image files are saved on my device and separated in folders like this: (...)/Documents/1/image1.png.

Here is the code of the function where I'm trying to get the image

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromDevice:(NSString *) fileName 
                        idImage:(int)        idImage{

    NSString *path;

    path = [[self dataFilePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",idImage]];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:fileName];

    NSLog(@"path = %@", path);

    NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:deviceImageUrl];
    UIImage *deviceImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return deviceImage;

}
```

And this is the function to get the path to the device folder that's working fine:

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return documentsDirectory;

}
```

But when I set the **NSURL *deviceImageUrl** with **[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path]** the deviceImageUrl becomes ***nil***.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying on simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
//NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:deviceImageUrl];
//UIImage *deviceImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];    
UIImage *deviceImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]autorelease];
```

Comment: try to do this : NSString *path = [[NSString alloc]init] instead of just using convenient constructor ; dont forget to release it

Comment: same problem...the path is probably fine...because the NSLog is printing the right path...so the NSURL *deviceImageUrl that is with trouble

Comment: This is really a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: works for me : UIImage *images = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];  don't forget to release

Comment: Thank you! And I've added the autorelease, because I have to return the UIImage

Answer (score 1):

Try using fileURLWithPath: instead of URLWithString: ;)

```
NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; // autoreleased url
```

I always mess up with these two methods, too ... they're making me crazy.

Comment: [NSURL initWithPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c17ea0

Comment: You aren't supposed to call initWithPath:. Call [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath]; this is a class method and [is implemented in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL).

Comment: hmm...your answer was correct too...I didn't wrote the right code...sorry =/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use initWithString: , this must conform to URL format as described in RFCs. If you just want to use a system path, use this : (don't forget to release after use it)

```
NSURL *deviceImageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
```